# reading images from a word file and display in the jframe

Tags: java, ms-word

How to read image from a word document file and display in jframe?

Answer (score 1):

To parse office documents (including MS Word files) in Java, I suggest you use the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library.

Comment: with this Apache POI is it possible even images in word file in java

Answer (score 0):

Use Jakarta POI to read word file. Then display the content in JFrame as you want. You can also use OpenOffice to embed Word document directly.

Comment: with this Apache POI is it possible even images in word file in java