# how to retrieve image from a word file and display using java

Tags: java, ms-word

I want to read ms word document and display in java. if there are images in between word file, then how to proceed and how to retrieve them

Comment: How many times are you going to post the same darn question??? [how-to-read-content-from-ms-word-using-jakarta-poi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990139/how-to-read-content-from-ms-word-using-jakarta-poi); [reading-images-from-a-word-file-and-display-in-the-jframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986984/reading-images-from-a-word-file-and-display-in-the-jframe)

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) project and see if they have something to do that.

Comment: He's already been told to do this in his several previous threads.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question